# document createElement shortest syntax

Tags: javascript, dojo, element, document, createelement

I'm looking for the shortest syntax which could provide me the same result as this dojo line:

```
var divblock5 = dojo.create("div", {className: "barlittle", id: "block5"});
```

but I want to use plain JavaScript instead of dojo framework. I have a lot of dynamic element creation and I want to make my code short as possible.

Comment: Create a function that does the same thing. Create an element, loop through the object applying the attributes, and finally return the element. Seems simple.

Comment: You'll need to write some wrapper, which in its code will be pretty much the same as the respective dojo code.

Comment: Read about [JsonML](http://www.jsonml.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
createElement = function(type, className, id) {
    var element = document.createElement(type);
    element.className = className;
    element.id = id;

    return element;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

```
var create = function(element, properties) {
    var elmt = document.createElement(element);
    for (var prop in properties) {
        elmt[prop] = properties[prop];
    }
    return elmt;
}

create("div", {className: "barlittle", id: "block5"});
```

Or, my personal favorite that simply takes HTML and converts it to a DOM node :

```
var elmtify(html) {
    var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    wrapper.innerHTML = html;
    return wrapper.firstChild;
}

elmtify('<div class="barlittle" id="block5"></div>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check put-selector: https://github.com/kriszyp/put-selector.

Comment: Amazing library. It does exactly what the question asks for.

Answer (score 1):

Since this seems to be a still open question I'm adding my method, which is almost the same as Tom said but my approach takes into account style information:

```
function createElement(tag, attrs) {
  if(!tag) throw new SyntaxError("'tag' not defined"); // In case you forget

  var ele = document.createElement(tag), attrName, styleName;
  if(attrs) for(attrName in attrs) {
    if(attrName === "style")
      for(styleName in attrs.style) {ele.style[styleName] = attrs.style[styleName];}
    else
      ele[attrName] = attrs[attrName];
  }
  return ele;
}
```

So if you normally write, without any library:

```
var divBlock5 = document.createElement("div");
divBlock5.className = "barlittle";
divBlock5.id = "block5";
```

With the snippet Tom provided, you would just write:

```
var divBlock5 = createElement("div", {className:"barlittle", id:"block5"});
```

But say you want to add an independent style to your element. Then, with my addition, you write:

```
var divBlock5 = createElement("div", {className:"barlittle", id:"block5", style:{color:"#08A", fontWeight:"bold"}});
```

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
function createElement(tag, attrs, html) {
    if (!tag) throw new SyntaxError("'tag' not defined"); // In case you forget

    var ele = document.createElement(tag),
        attrName, styleName;
    if (attrs)
        for (attrName in attrs) {
            if (attrName === "style")
                for (styleName in attrs.style) { ele.style[styleName] = attrs.style[styleName]; }
            else if (attrs[attrName])
                ele.setAttribute(attrName, attrs[attrName]);
        }
    if (html)
        ele.innerHTML = html;
    return ele;
}
```

This solution builds on what Tom and Xch3l proposed, but it adds support for passing custom attributes to be applied to the DOM element. Which attributes exist as properties for any given DOM element depends on the DOM element's type, so using the element's `setAttribute` method is a more robust solution.

Note that you will need to pass a "class" attribute instead of "className," and that this solution also adds support for an optional HTML string that can be passed as the third parameter.

Here is an example of how to use the function:

```
var divBlock5 = createElement("div", {class:"barlittle", "data-my-custom-attribute":"lorem ipsum", id:"block5", style:{color:"#08A", fontWeight:"bold"}},`<h5>An Optional String of HTML to be Inserted Inside the Newly Created Element</h5><p>Preserve Line Spacing by Using Backticks Instead of Quotes</p>`);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function FcreateSingleElement(elem,arrClass,arrAttr,textc,arrChilds){
  let el = document.createElement(elem)
  if(!!arrClass) arrClass.forEach(e => {el.classList.add(e)});
  if(!!arrAttr) arrAttr.forEach(e => { el.setAttribute(e[0],e[1])});
  if(!!textc) el.textContent = textc;
  if(!!arrChilds) arrChilds.forEach(e => { el.append(FcreateSingleElement(...e))});

  return el;

}

FcreateSingleElement("div", ["class1"], [["id","element-id"]], 0,[["div", ["class2","class3"], [["id","element-child1"],["data-key","1"],["disabled","true"]], "child 1",0],["div", ["class4"], [["id","element-child2"]], 0,[["span", ["class5","class6"], [["id","grand-child1"],["data-key","2"],["disabled","true"]], "grand child 1",0],["span", ["class5","class6"], [["id","grand-child2"],["data-key","3"],["disabled","false"]], "grand child 2",0]]]])
```